# How to open old version Telerik reporting designer on VS 2022

Tags: telerik, visual-studio-2022, telerik-reporting

We have a lot of reports done with Telerik Reporting 2019 R3 (c# version, not the trdp/trdx one). Now we are using Visual Studio 2022 to develope, but we cannot upgrade TR to 2022 version (not this year).

The problem is that we don't have designer support on VS 2022: the .cs report can only be opened as normal code and not with designer tools. In VS 2019 we had Telerik reporting plug-in/extension, but on VS2022, we don't have one. Is there a way to use designer in VS2022 with that "old" report, without upgrade the version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telerik Reporting is only supported in Visual Studio 2022 from version [2021 SP1](https://www.telerik.com/forums/visual-studio-2022-supported-reporting-versions) upwards.

You would either need to upgrade the Telerik Reporting or remain on your current version and continue to use Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: So... We have no way